# conflicts between javascript code and browser addon/extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am the owner and developer of a e-commerce website.

Every single day some potential customers call us because can not order, we investigate a little bit and inevitably discover he can not because of some js errors.

We check his browser addons/extensions, disable some or all, and the JS errors disappear.

The JS are always different from each other, and the addons/extension vary; it happens with Chrome, IE, Firefox, indifferently. Usually are some sort of coupon/deals addons/extension like DealSpy.

And I don't have any data to support this but I believe these cases had a spike since we moved to angularjs.

I am wondering if there's anything I can do; I can't disable their addons/extension programmatically from my code I guess, but somehow catch those errors and manage them?

Any advice from anyone who faced same or similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is likely no way to answer this properly as it depends on the code of your site and the add-ons breaking it, none of which you supply...

Anyway, try to reproduce the error and contact the add-on authors in question.
There might be ways to work around particular issues, but that would be case-by-case and dependent on the actual code.

Also, in case of Firefox add-ons, if you encounter an add-on that just "breaks the web" (or part of it: your website, maybe others), consider filing a [Tech Evangelism :: Add-ons](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tech%20Evangelism&component=Add-ons) bug. Mozilla and/or the add-ons editors team may then take appropriate steps according to the [Add-on guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_guidelines).

Not sure if there is something similar for Chrome... Their [Help section](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/troubleshooter/2589181?hl=en&ref_topic=1212375#ts=2589435) just says to contact the actual extension author. So unless it is a security sensitive bug, you shouldn't expect any assistance from Google.

Comment: I didn't add any code because the errors are usually inside libraries. The last ones I personally saw where inside angular.min.js so outside of my control.

Comment: So work-arounds are not really an option, unless you want to maintain a fork of angular (which no sane person really would). So you're left with contacting the authors and "authorities".

Comment: Which means I can do nothing. Those addons/extensions like dealspy are as close to scam as you can get.

Comment: Well, for the Firefox extension you could file a bug, as stated. There might even be reliable ways to detect particular add-ons and e.g. display a message to the user.